# Why is a C# Dictionary with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase slower than using ToLowerInvariant on the keys?

Tags: c#, string, performance, dictionary, comparison

In a discussion with @mjwills on performance and preference when counting file extensions, my testing showed that using `ToLowerInvariant` on the keys (Invariant culture is recommended by Microsoft for filename comparisons) is faster than using a `Dictionary` that uses `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why or what might be faster/better than using `ToLowerInvariant` on the keys?

Here is a test program:

```
void Main() {
    var numRepeats = 1000;
    var numExtensions = 10;
    var minFilesPerDir = 10;
    var maxFilesPerDir = 100;
    var minDirs = 100;
    var maxDirs = 500;

    var r = new Random(42);

    var lowers = 'a'.To('z');
    var uppers = 'A'.To('Z');
    var digits = '0'.To('9');
    var chars = uppers.Concat(lowers).Concat(digits).ToArray();

    var extensions = new List<string>();
    for (int j1 = 0; j1 < numExtensions; ++j1) {
        var extLen = r.Next(3, 4);
        var extSB = new StringBuilder(4);
        for (int j2 = 0; j2 < extLen; ++j2) {
            extSB.Append(chars[r.Next(0, chars.Length)]);
        }
        var ext = extSB.ToString();
        extensions.Add(ext);
    }


    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Restart();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < numRepeats; ++rpt) {
        var numDirs = r.Next(minDirs, maxDirs);
        for (int dirNum = 0; dirNum < numDirs; ++dirNum) {
            var d = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            var numFiles = r.Next(minFilesPerDir, maxFilesPerDir);
            for (int j1 = 0; j1 < numFiles; ++j1) {
                var ext = extensions.TakeRandom1(r);
                if (d.TryGetValue(ext, out var val))
                    d[ext] = val + 1;
                else
                    d[ext] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"OrdinalIgnoreCase Dictionary Elapsed: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

    sw.Restart();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < numRepeats; ++rpt) {
        var numDirs = r.Next(minDirs, maxDirs);
        for (int dirNum = 0; dirNum < numDirs; ++dirNum) {
            var d = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
            var numFiles = r.Next(minFilesPerDir, maxFilesPerDir);
            for (int j1 = 0; j1 < numFiles; ++j1) {
                var ext = extensions.TakeRandom1(r);
                ext = ext.ToLowerInvariant();
                if (d.TryGetValue(ext, out var val))
                    d[ext] = val + 1;
                else
                    d[ext] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Ordinal Dictionary+ToLower Elapsed: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

    sw.Restart();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < numRepeats; ++rpt) {
        var numDirs = r.Next(minDirs, maxDirs);
        for (int dirNum = 0; dirNum < numDirs; ++dirNum) {
            var d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            var numFiles = r.Next(minFilesPerDir, maxFilesPerDir);
            for (int j1 = 0; j1 < numFiles; ++j1) {
                var ext = extensions.TakeRandom1(r);
                ext = ext.ToLowerInvariant();
                if (d.TryGetValue(ext, out var val))
                    d[ext] = val + 1;
                else
                    d[ext] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"ToLower Elapsed: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

    sw.Restart();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < numRepeats; ++rpt) {
        var numDirs = r.Next(minDirs, maxDirs);
        for (int dirNum = 0; dirNum < numDirs; ++dirNum) {
            var d = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            var numFiles = r.Next(minFilesPerDir, maxFilesPerDir);
            for (int j1 = 0; j1 < numFiles; ++j1) {
                var ext = extensions.TakeRandom1(r);
                if (d.TryGetValue(ext, out var val))
                    d[ext] = val + 1;
                else
                    d[ext] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"InvariantCultureIgnoreCase Dictionary Elapsed: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
}

public static class ExtExt {
    public static IEnumerable<char> To(this char startCh, char endCh) => Enumerable.Range(startCh, endCh - startCh + 1).Select(n => (char)n);

    public static T TakeRandom1<T>(this IList<T> src, Random r) => src[r.Next(0, src.Count)];
}
```

And here is a sample run:

```
OrdinalIgnoreCase Dictionary Elapsed: 1685ms
Ordinal Dictionary+ToLower Elapsed: 2360ms
ToLower Elapsed: 2396ms
InvariantCultureIgnoreCase Dictionary Elapsed: 6255ms
```

This is on .Net framework 4.7.2 x64 - .Net Core is somewhat faster for the first three:

```
OrdinalIgnoreCase Dictionary Elapsed: 1184ms
Ordinal Dictionary+ToLower Elapsed: 1788ms
ToLower Elapsed: 1754ms
InvariantCultureIgnoreCase Dictionary Elapsed: 6130ms
```

Comment: Do you expect otherwise for some reason? `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` doing more work than other variants, so it takes more time.

Comment: @PetSerAl `ToLowerInvariant` should be doing similar work in a different place?

Comment: For example look at [this](https://ideone.com/V1Xca9). It have two different strings, but `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` is able to say that them are the "same", that require additional work. But if you do filename comparisons, then you should use `OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Microsoft [recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolowerinvariant?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) using `ToLowerInvariant` so I assume comparison should also use `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: That recommendation is about case transformation. `OrdinalIgnoreCase` also do case transformation with invariant culture.

Comment: @PetSerAl Interesting that `OrginalIgnoreCase` is so much faster than `Orginal+ToLowerInvariant` then.

Comment: Invariant culture will be slower than Ordinal, since ordinal looks directly at the code bytes and invariant has to look at the character mappings(?). It makes a difference in results, though. If you want `ß` to equal `ss`, for example, then you'd have to use invariant. If you look at the [best practices for using strings in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx), you'll see that `Ordinal` is preferred in most cases.

Comment: I don't understand why you have `uppers` defined in the range `'a'.To('z')`. Shouldn't those be called `lowers`?

Comment: @RufusL LOL - yes, just a typo.

Comment: @NetMage Difference between `OrginalIgnoreCase` and `Orginal+ToLowerInvariant` can be much more extreme if you craft [special case](https://ideone.com/y8cyui). Comparer does not need to case transform the whole string if it sees them different by first character. It also can do transformation on fly with fixed extra memory and not to allocate whole new string object which need to garbage collected afterwards. More work => more time.

Comment: @PetSerAl Since Comparer can short circuit case transformation you would think it normally do less work than ToLowerInvariant+OrdinalComparer? Your comment seems to imply Comparer would be faster, but it is much, much slower. I guess the overhead of the Invariant compare is very high. OTOH, Comparer isn't being used to compare in `Dictionary`, invariant hashcode is being used, which is apparently (much) slower than ToLowerInvariant+regular hashcode, which doesn't seem entirely reasonable. CaseInsensitive Invariant Hashcode implementation is not in C#, so not sure why it is so slow.